# Matlab data interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a doubt regarding the function interp1 in matlab.
I have an X array of 248 elements with its corresponding Y array. I would like to build a correspondence between the values on the array X and a custom array of gray scale values,e.g. linspace(5,250,248). I don't want to take the value 0 and 255. If i define that max(X) has the value 250 and the min(X) as the value 0, which is the corresponding gray scale value of a generic x_i? 
I though to use interp1 but my code is not working. Some suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are trying to do. Aren't you confusing image normalization with interpolation?

Comment: No no, i don't want to do image normalization. I try to explain better.

Comment: Can you post your code and the error message you're getting?

Comment: The question is really unclear. Impossible to undestand clearly. Try to re-write, please. If a piece of code can help, please insert it.

Answer (score 0):

`I = mat2gray(A,[amin amax])` converts the matrix `A` to an intensity image `I` that contains values in the range 0 (black) to 1 (white). `amin` and `amax` are the values in `A` that correspond to 0 and 1 in `I`. Values less than `amin` become 0, and values greater than `amax` become 1.